# SharePoint 2013 Updatepanel Idle

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, web-parts

I have implemented AJAX update panel on my SharePoint visual web part. The web part contains two dropdownlists and and a grid surrounded by update panel.

The page is working fine in Chrome/Safari/IE until I leave the page idle for a while. The page will then cause a full postback in Chrome/Safari, but not in IE. In IE its still working perfectly. I've looked at the requests in Fiddler and see that SharePoint is making a request to /_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSitePages%2fIssues.aspx

In IE this does not happen. Have anyone else encountered this problem. I've been looking for a solution the last two days and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by placing a timer in the updatepanel to do a refresh every minute. It's not pretty, but it works.